# What prizes can I win from playing Justice Monsters Five?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

There are pinball machines at some outposts that let you play this minigame. After getting bored with playing it and exiting back out to the main screen, I noticed that I received an accessory.

- What are the different prizes you can receive?
- How is this the prize you receive determined? Is it based on your score, the number of the gold tiles you collect, or some combination of both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article on [iDigitalTimes](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/final-fantasy-xv-justice-monsters-five-rewards-list-every-item-snag-pinball-mini-game-570990) lists the rewards you can obtain from Justice Monsters 5, which is based on the amount of chests you were able to collect

> The rewards you obtain by playing Justice Monsters Five depend on the number of treasure chests you manage to collect. (They’re the golden rectangles that pop up in the slot-machine reels when you clear a round; we thought they were planks of wood at first.)

**10 Gil Rewards**

```
2 -- Potion
5 -- Hi-Potion
10 -- Elixir
15 -- Hi-Elixir
20 -- Garnet Bracelet
25 -- Carbon Bangle
30 -- Amethyst Bracelet
35 -- Titanium Bangle
40 -- Mega Phoenix
45 -- Sapphire Bracelet
50 -- Gold Bangle
60 -- Oracle Earring
70 -- Ruby Bracelet
80 -- Platinum Bangle
90 -- Emerald Bracelet
99 -- Celestriad
```

**10,000 Gil Rewards**

```
5 -- Hi-Potion
10 -- Mega Phoenix
15 -- Ruby Bracelet
20 -- Platinum Bangle
25 -- Emerald Bracelet
30 -- Centurion Bangle
35 -- Mystic Circlet
40 -- Moogle Charm
45 -- Legatus Bangle
50 -- Blue Diamond Bracelet
60 -- Gigas Bangle
70 -- Assist Suit
80 -- Dark Matter Bracelet
90 -- Onion Bangle
99 - Wind-up Lord Vexxos
```

Also mentioned at the end of the article, the final reward contains some handy usages

> In case you're wondering, the game's final reward, the Wind-up Lord Vexxos, can be sold for a whopping 500,000 Gil or used to make some intensely powerful spells in crafting.